# Proving Reflexivity, Symmetry and Transitivity of a Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm currently taking an intro discrete math course, and I'm having some trouble understanding the rules of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. The book isn't making a lot of sense to me, and my professors examples haven't been very clear. I have two problems in which I'm not confident in my answers.

1) There is a set S = {1, 2, 3, 4}, and a relation R on S, defined by R = {(1,1),(3,4),(4,2),(4,1),(3,2)}. I need to determine if R is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

A relation is reflexive if, and only if, xRx for all elements x in S, correct?
So there is only one tuple where x relates to itself, so R **is not reflexive**

A relation is symmetric if, and only if, if xRy then yRx for all (x,y) pairs in S, correct?
In this relation, there are no instances where x relates to y and y relates to x, so R **is not symmetric**

A relation is transitive if, and only if, xRy and yRz then xRz for all x,y,z pairs in S, correct? This relation has one instance of transitivity, where 3R4 and 4R2 then 3R2, but transitivity doesn't hold true for all pairs (pairs including 1), so R **is not transitive**?

2) There is a set S = {all real numbers}, and a relation R defined by: R is the set of all ordered pairs (x,y) such that x and y are real numbers, 1 < x < 2 AND x = y. I need to determine if R is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Since, by definition of R, x = y wouldn't that mean that every (x,y) tuple that would be part of R would contain an x and y such that x = y, so the elements would relate to themselves? So they would be reflexive. But this relation is also limited to 1 < x <2. So this relation obviously doesn't hold all possible ordered pairs possible in the set of real numbers. So I would say that R is **not reflexive**. Is that correct reasoning?

By definition of R, I know that x = y so y = x, so the proposition **if xRy then yRx** would be true in this case. So I would think that R **is symmetric**, but I don't know how the stipulation 1 < x <2 plays into this. Also, This relation won't have every ordered pair in S, so would that mean it's not symmetric?

You could prove transitivity with the transitive law **if x=y and y=z then x=z**, but again I don't see how it would apply to all ordered pairs or satisfy the 1 < x < 2, so I'd say **not transitive**

---

tl;dr:
I'm having problems proving reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity of the following:
1) set S = {1,2,3,4} relation R = {(1,1),(3,4),(4,2),(4,1),(3,2)}
2) set S = {all real numbers} relation R = {(x,y)|1 < x < 2 and x=y}

Comment: Everything seems good to me!

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi I'm confused as to how the relation in number 2 is symmetric. The definition of symmetry says that every ordered pair in the set of real numbers has to satisfy "if xRy then yRx". How does this relation accomplish this?

Comment: You gave the correct explanation there. $xRx\iff xRx$, that is trivial. When $x=y$ which is the case here $xRy\iff yRx$. Note that a set containing all "reflexive elements"as I would call it is trivially symmetric and transitive.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi So as an example, if I had a set S={1,2,3,4} and a relation R={(1,1),(3,3)}, R would not be reflexive, but it would be symmetric and transitive?

Comment: Yes! You got it. :)

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Oh, I see! So you can test for symmetry by checking _if 1R1 then 1R1_ and _if 3R3 then 3R3_, and both of those propositions are true, so the relation is symmetric? The thing that is confusing me is that the definition of symmetry and transitivity states that every ordered pair from the set has to satisfy the proposition, correct? So why is R symmetric if it only has those two reflexive elements?

Comment: Definition of symmetric relation: It says, for each $(x,y)$ in $R$, $(y,x)$ must be in $R$. It doesn't say every possible $(x,y)$ should be in $R$ and then $(y,x)$ too. If the second definition was the case, then symmetric and transitive would have implied reflexive, which is clearly not the case.